# Google Authentications Error in LWC Component in Mobile Publisher Community App

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I hope this message finds you well. We are currently facing a critical issue with Google Authentications in our Lightning Web Component (LWC) within the Mobile Publisher Community App. The specific error we are encountering is {"error":"popup_blocked_by_browser"}.

This error is preventing users from completing the authentication process, and we need to address it urgently to ensure a seamless user experience. We suspect that it may be related to popup blocking by certain browsers.

Code : (Below Code working in Desktop not working mobile app)
Step 1 :
// Load the Google Sign-In script
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
//script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
script.onload = () => this.initializeGoogleSignIn();
document.head.appendChild(script);

- // we call the gapi.load method.
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {});

Step 2:
gapi.auth2.init({
client_id: '57975150250-6a4avq98onf6lvk026vhggg8vumh80iu.apps.googleusercontent.com', // Replace with your actual client ID
scope: 'openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events%27),
plugin_name:'login',
immediate: false,
prompt: 'consent',
cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
fetch_basic_profile: true
}).then((authInstance) => {
console.log("gapi init in");
console.log(authInstance);
//var authIns = authInstance;

authInstance.signIn().then(googleUser => {
console.log('googleUser', JSON.stringify(googleUser));
this.showSuccessAlert("googleUser", ""+JSON.stringify(googleUser));
const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
console.log('User ID:', profile.getId());
console.log('User Name:', profile.getName());
console.log('User Email:', profile.getEmail());

// Additional logic for Google Calendar integration
}).catch((error) => {
//console.error(error);
this.showFailureAlert("googleUser", ""+JSON.stringify(error));
});
});

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXwPE.png)

Comment: Please correctly format your post. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Review how other questions about programming format the code and error messages. Since this is a programming question, I recommend that you delete this post and create one on StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/).